# How to get date from timestamp in Aurora postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, aws-aurora-serverless

Thing's I have tried
I used to_char to get the date from timestamp but I am getting wrong date for this, When I use the date function I just get the timestamp as the result again. In normal postgresql this is working fine but when I use Aurora postgresql I am getting the below Result.

```
1."SELECT to_char(datetime, 'YYYY-MM-DD') as date,datetime  from call_schedule"

result:

"date": "2022-10-07",
"datetime": "2022-10-06T20:00:00.000Z"

2. "SELECT date(datetime) as date, datetime  from call_schedule"

result:

"date": "2022-10-03T18:30:00.000Z",
"datetime": "2022-10-04T07:35:00.000Z"
```

Comment: `date(datetime)` or `datetime::date` **will** return a `date` value. If you are seeing something different, then your application/frontend/SQL tool does this.

Comment: I used postman to hit my api endpoint

Comment: Then Postman is unable to distinguish between a `date` and a `timestamp`

Comment: query is executed in DB right?

Comment: Yes, but Postman _displays_ the result. https://dbfiddle.uk/NCNXxCM7

Comment: I guess this is something to do with Aurora postgresql serverless v2.